# Proof check: A solution of Bernoullis's equation that is not identically $0$ has no zero

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I'm trying to prove

*Given the Bernoulli's equation*

$$
y' + g(x)y + h(x)y^\alpha = 0 
$$

*on an interval $J$,  with $\alpha$ an **integer** and $\alpha \geq 2$ , show directly (without using uniqueness theorem) that a solution $y\not\equiv 0$ has no zero on $J$. Here we assume $y \in C^1(J)$, and $g, h \in C(J)$.*

My proof is like this:

Arguing by contradiction, and suppose $y(\xi) = 0$ for some $\xi \in J$, and since $y$ is not identically $0$ we let the zero $\xi$ to be isolated. Writing

$$
|y'| = |g(x)y + h(x)y^\alpha| = |y||g(x) + h(x)y^{\alpha - 1}|, 
$$

since $g$, $h$, $y$ are assumed continuous on any closed subset $I \ni \xi $ in $J$ and $y^{\alpha-1}$ is not problematic as $\alpha - 1 \geq 1$, and that $y$ not vanishing near $\xi$ by our assumption, we have

$$
|\frac{y'}{y}| = |g(x) + h(x)y^{\alpha - 1}| \leq M, \; x \in I \;\;\;\;\; (*)
$$

for some $M > 0$. Then integrating from $\xi + \delta$ to $x \in I$, (note that the integration on the left is improper)

$$
\int_{\xi+\delta}^{x} |\frac{y'}{y}| dx = [\log |y|]_{\xi+\delta}^x \leq M (x- \xi - \delta). \;\;\;\;\; (**)
$$

But $\log |y(x)| $ gose to $-\infty$  as $x$ tends to $\xi$ and $y(x)$ tends to $0$, thus there is a contradiction.

I'm not sure whether my estimation on the boundedness of $|\frac{y'}{y}|$ in $(*)$ is correct or not, so is the way I deal with the imporper integration in $(**)$.

Thank you for your help.